# How do I add another listener in the main .java file

Tags: android, button, project, listener, addition

When i add another button (nextButton2) in (main activity. x m l) !
Now i want to make button open (third screen.x m l)

can you help me to to add listener to it in this android project in (main.java)  but failed??

[link original project](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=1670)

[my project link](http://www.megafileupload.com/en/file/448924/secondscreen-rar.html)

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the source code directly on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

followed by existing logic from your code, this is how it could look like:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        findViewById(R.id.nextButton).setOnClickListener(new handleButton());
        findViewById(R.id.nextButton2).setOnClickListener(new handleButton2());
    }
    class handleButton implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Screen2.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        }
    }

    class handleButton2 implements OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Screen3.class);
            startActivity(intent);  
        }
    }
}
```

It assumes that you already created new activity called Screen3.java and add it to manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="your.project.package.Screen3" android:label="@string/app_name" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to achieve that:

#### Anonymous listeners

If you need the listeners only once:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // your first listener here
        });
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            // your second listener here
        });
    }
}
```

#### Multiple nested classes

If you want to re-use the listeners in the same class:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(new Listener1());
        button2.setOnClickListener(new Listener2());
    }

    class Listener1 implements OnClickListener {
        // your first listener here
    }

    class Listener2 implements OnClickListener {
        // your second listener here
    }
}
```

#### Multiple top-level classes

If you want to re-use the listeners in more than one class:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        button1.setOnClickListener(new Listener1());
        button2.setOnClickListener(new Listener2());
    }
}

class Listener1 implements OnClickListener {
    // your first listener here
}

class Listener2 implements OnClickListener {
    // your second listener here
}
```